# MongoDB database is getting reset randonmly

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I have created a instance of mongodb on AWS EC2 Instance.

I have 2 Spring boot/microservices connected to this database. One is just inserting the data and other is fetching data. In my microservices, I dont have any delete operation and no such code is provided atany time so by mistake data getting deleted scenario will not occure.

```
**But some how mongodb database is getting reset/cleared. All database is getting deleted.**
```

I have checked the mongodb configuration and I haven't explicitly changed anything.

Mongodb is community edition.

> On spring boot microservices, I am directly using the Mongorepository
> JPA to insert or fetch the data.

I dont have any constraints in POJOs.

> Can someone point out what might be the issue? Does mongodb has any
> default setting for resetting the database?

Comment: What kind of EC2 instance do you have and where did you store the data? Is it on EBS or did you perhaps put it in the ephemeral instance storage? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Comment: Make sure you enabled authentication.  There are really stupid people out there who find it funny to connect to the MongoDB port of random IP addresses and delete the data.

Comment: EC2 Instance -> t2.micro.    dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
@IanMercer

Comment: yes i have enabled authentication @Joe

Comment: The mongod log would be the next place to check, perhaps set the log level higher to get more detail.

Comment: Can you please post your entries from application.properties?

Comment: @Amit
 spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://XXXX:XXXX@ec2-13-X-X-X.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/XXXX

Comment: See the MongoDB guide on this topic "However, when an instance is terminated the ephemeral drive and its data is lost."  This includes restarts initiated by Amazon not you: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/selecting-aws-storage-for-mongodb-deployments-ephemeral-vs-ebs  A single instance running on ephemeral storage *will* lose data.